# Column Values Customisation- Export Excel in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, export

I have to export gridview in to the excel sheet 2003.  With my code I can Export the data into eXcel Sheet directly. But If there is a null value for the column, Then how do I replace with empty string in Excel sheet. There is a date column which is null, is there any event handler that occurs between export button click and the loading the data into excel. If there is one I can compare the values in the database and can replace the null value with empty String. in the evnt handler.

Please point me in right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of the export button, you can iterate through your grid rows and replace whatever you need. For example, the code below will replace `:` with `.`:

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    string attachment = "attachment; filename=SummaryReport" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xls";

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    foreach (GridViewRow grdRow in grdProjectTasks.Rows)
    {
        Label lblActualDuration = (Label)grdRow.FindControl("lblActualDuration");

        lblActualDuration.Text = lblActualDuration.Text.Replace(":", ".");
    }

    grdProjectTasks.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```